# Deklination des Wortes "viel-"

Tags: grammar, adjective, declension

Wie ist die Deklination des Wortes *viel-*?

**1. Frage:**
Gibt es das Wort *viel-* im Singular oder nicht? *(Bitte kleines Beispiel oder einen Link geben).*

Ich kann nicht verstehen, wie (mit dieser Bedeutung) dieses Wort im Singular genutzt werden kann.

Ist das unten richtig *(falls es einen Singular von* viel- *gibt)*?

```
SINGULAR(?)   
Nominativ: vieler gute  Hund
Akkusativ: vielen guten Hund
Dativ    : vielem guten Hund
Genitiv  : vieles guten Hundes
```

**2. Frage:**
Wie ist die Adjektivdeklination von *viel-* im Plural? *(Bitte bestätigen oder einen Link geben.)*

Ist das unten richtig?

```
PLURAL    
Nominativ: viele  gute  Katzen
Akkusativ: viele  gute  Katzen
Dativ    : vielen guten Katzen
Genitiv  : vieler guten Katzen
```

EDIT

So gibt es eine Deklination nur für ein Hauptwort, das nicht zählbar ist? Wie mit alles?

EDIT

Viele Leute sagen schnell, daß eine Frage zu einfach ist.

In Meiner Antwort steht, daß keine Deklination im Singular für viel- gibt.

Ich habe ausdrücklich über die singulare Deklination gefragt, weil ich eine Deklination im Singular gefunden habe. http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:viel

Comment: http://www.canoo.net/inflection/viel:A

Comment: Lieber Gott! Ich kann nicht verstehen. Endlich gibt es eine Deklination. Ich möchte mit einer Person über dass zu sprechen... Ist meine singularische deklination richtig???

Comment: @Loong Stimmt es aber eine Deklination im Sigular oder nicht? Wird das von Leuten, die diese Sprache sprechen, gemacht? Ich habe z.B. das Wort vieles gefunden...

Comment: Zweites Ergebnis für Google-Suche nach "viel deklination": http://www.dsporto.de/ubungen/deklination17.htm

Answer (score 2):

Wenn du die [Diskussion zur von dir verlinkten Flexionstabelle](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion_Diskussion:viel) öffnest, gibt es dort einen [Link zu einer weiteren Diskussion](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Benutzer_Diskussion:Dr._Karl-Heinz_Best/Archiv_12.1#Adjektiv.2C_flektierte_Formen), die dir meines Erachtens weiterhelfen wird.

Die wichtigsten Informationen sind in Dr. Karl-Heinz Bests zweitem Kommentar zu finden:

> Zur Flexion von "viel" als Indefinitpronomen:
>
> [...]
>
> Maskulinum: im Singular nur bei Stoffnamen anwendbar, die das semantische Merkmal [- zählbar] haben:
>
> Nom.: viel Dunst (ich persönlich halte *vieler Dunst zumindest für ungebräuchlich, wenn es überhaupt möglich sein sollte)
>
> Gen: viel(en) Dunstes
>
> Dat.: vielem Dunst (Da das Substantiv keine Flexionsendung hat, ist sie bei "viel" nötig.)
>
> Akk. viel Dunst(ich halte "vielen Dunst" für möglich.)
>
> [...]
>
> u.v.m.

Answer (score -2):

Der Plural ist richitg. Im Singular wird "viel" nicht gebeugt, also (ich habe das Substantiv durch ein geeigneteres ersetzt und einen möglichen Satzanfang für jeden Fall geschrieben)

```
Nominativ: Viel guter Wille ist benötigt, um ...
Akkusativ: Man braucht viel guten Willen, um ...
Dativ    : Mit viel gutem Willen könnte man ...
Genitiv  : Trotz viel guten Willens ...
```

Comment: Jein. Man kann es ungebeugt lassen, darf es aber gerne beugen, und es damit schöner klingen lassen. Außerdem ist der Plural des Fragenden nicht durchgehend richtig.