# Viel or viele in this context?

Tags: gender, adjective-ending

In this video it says:

> Du hast **viel** Erfahrung mit Online-Shops. (https://youtu.be/JPrv_TmmnYg?t=1699)

Shouldn't it be *viele Erfahrung* because the word *Erfahrung* is feminine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deklination des Wortes "viel-"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20742/deklination-des-wortes-viel)

Comment: The explanation is in Duden's article for "viel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how *viel, genug, wenig* etc. behave when used pronimially when specifying the quantity. I.e. this is not an adjective in this case.

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/viel_zahlreich_vielerlei
https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/vielwenig

A more elaborated explanation from the Duden grammar (starting from "die unflektierten") https://docplayer.org/151306581-Nomenartige-pronomen-langfassung.html