Forms of "viel"
I've read this sentence on a website

Wir machen oft Dinge zusammen und haben viel Spaß.

Why "viel" is not declined as "vielen", since it qualifies the accusative noun "Spaß"?

Same question as https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/55086/viel-or-viele-in-this-context

@RHa except that question is closed and its answer has more links than content and does not adress countability.

It's more clear if we compare these two cases:
Ich habe viel Spaß.
Ich habe großen Spaß.

The second one is clear. "haben" requires the accusative, "Spaß" is masculine and accusative, and "großen" is a suitable adjective for "Spaß".
However, "viel" is not a suitable adjective for "Spaß". The whole idea of the word "viel/viele“ is that it applies to an amount, which can either be counted ("Hier sind viele Hühner") or at least regarded as abstract amount ("Hier ist viel Wasser").
Therefore you can not say i.e. "Der viel/viele Spaß, den wir gestern gehabt haben". This is not a problem of grammar, but of logic: "viel" and "Spaß" simply don't go together.
HOWEVER you can regard "Spaß haben" not as "haben" (= to own) + "Spaß", but you can see it as idiomatic expression. "Spaß haben” = "to have pleasure".
In this respect, the "viel" can be an adverb to the "verb" Spaß haben, and as an adverb, it is not declensed.
